# having error with connection between java and mysql with cayenne module

Tags: java, mysql, apache-cayenne

```
Jul 03, 2013 9:19:08 AM org.apache.cayenne.configuration.XMLDataChannelDescriptorLoader load
INFO: Loading XML configuration resource from file:/C:/Users/Shadi/Documents/spring%20tool%20projects/myBookstore/target/classes/cayenne-project.xml
Jul 03, 2013 9:19:08 AM org.apache.cayenne.configuration.XMLDataChannelDescriptorLoader$DataSourceChildrenHandler createChildTagHandler
INFO: loading user name and password.
Jul 03, 2013 9:19:08 AM org.apache.cayenne.log.CommonsJdbcEventLogger logPoolCreated
INFO: Created connection pool: jdbc:mysql://localhost/bookstore
    Driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    Min. connections in the pool: 1
    Max. connections in the pool: 1
Jul 03, 2013 9:19:08 AM org.apache.cayenne.log.CommonsJdbcEventLogger logConnectFailure
INFO: *** Connecting: FAILURE.
java.sql.SQLException: Can not load JDBC driver named 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver': com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.cayenne.conn.DriverDataSource.loadDriver(DriverDataSource.java:60)
    at org.apache.cayenne.conn.DriverDataSource.setDriverClassName(DriverDataSource.java:254)
    at org.apache.cayenne.conn.DriverDataSource.<init>(DriverDataSource.java:99)
    at org.apache.cayenne.conn.DriverDataSource.<init>(DriverDataSource.java:85)
    at org.apache.cayenne.conn.PoolManager.<init>(PoolManager.java:90)
    at org.apache.cayenne.configuration.server.XMLPoolingDataSourceFactory.getDataSource(XMLPoolingDataSourceFactory.java:64)
    at org.apache.cayenne.configuration.server.DelegatingDataSourceFactory.getDataSource(DelegatingDataSourceFactory.java:68)
    at org.apache.cayenne.configuration.server.DataDomainProvider.createAndInitDataDomain(DataDomainProvider.java:203)
    at org.apache.cayenne.configuration.server.DataDomainProvider.get(DataDomainProvider.java:111)
    at org.apache.cayenne.configuration.server.DataDomainProvider.get(DataDomainProvider.java:58)
    at org.apache.cayenne.di.spi.CustomProvidersProvider.get(CustomProvidersProvider.java:38)
    at org.apache.cayenne.di.spi.FieldInjectingProvider.get(FieldInjectingProvider.java:42)
    at org.apache.cayenne.di.spi.DefaultScopeProvider.get(DefaultScopeProvider.java:49)
    at org.apache.cayenne.di.spi.DefaultInjector.getInstance(DefaultInjector.java:107)
    at org.apache.cayenne.di.spi.FieldInjectingProvider.injectMember(FieldInjectingProvider.java:93)
    at org.apache.cayenne.di.spi.FieldInjectingProvider.injectMembers(FieldInjectingProvider.java:58)
    at org.apache.cayenne.di.spi.FieldInjectingProvider.get(FieldInjectingProvider.java:43)
    at org.apache.cayenne.di.spi.DefaultScopeProvider.get(DefaultScopeProvider.java:49)
    at org.apache.cayenne.di.spi.DefaultInjector.getInstance(DefaultInjector.java:103)
    at org.apache.cayenne.configuration.CayenneRuntime.getContext(CayenneRuntime.java:182)
    at mybookstore.Main.main(Main.java:23)

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.cayenne.configuration.server.DataDomainLoadException: [v.3.1M3 Sep 12 2011 19:59:45] Error loading DataChannel: 'Can not load JDBC driver named 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver': com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
    at org.apache.cayenne.configuration.server.DataDomainProvider.get(DataDomainProvider.java:117)
    at org.apache.cayenne.configuration.server.DataDomainProvider.get(DataDomainProvider.java:58)
    at org.apache.cayenne.di.spi.CustomProvidersProvider.get(CustomProvidersProvider.java:38)
    at org.apache.cayenne.di.spi.FieldInjectingProvider.get(FieldInjectingProvider.java:42)
    at org.apache.cayenne.di.spi.DefaultScopeProvider.get(DefaultScopeProvider.java:49)
    at org.apache.cayenne.di.spi.DefaultInjector.getInstance(DefaultInjector.java:107)
    at org.apache.cayenne.di.spi.FieldInjectingProvider.injectMember(FieldInjectingProvider.java:93)
    at org.apache.cayenne.di.spi.FieldInjectingProvider.injectMembers(FieldInjectingProvider.java:58)
    at org.apache.cayenne.di.spi.FieldInjectingProvider.get(FieldInjectingProvider.java:43)
    at org.apache.cayenne.di.spi.DefaultScopeProvider.get(DefaultScopeProvider.java:49)
    at org.apache.cayenne.di.spi.DefaultInjector.getInstance(DefaultInjector.java:103)
    at org.apache.cayenne.configuration.CayenneRuntime.getContext(CayenneRuntime.java:182)
    at mybookstore.Main.main(Main.java:23)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Can not load JDBC driver named 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver': com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.cayenne.conn.DriverDataSource.loadDriver(DriverDataSource.java:60)
    at org.apache.cayenne.conn.DriverDataSource.setDriverClassName(DriverDataSource.java:254)
    at org.apache.cayenne.conn.DriverDataSource.<init>(DriverDataSource.java:99)
    at org.apache.cayenne.conn.DriverDataSource.<init>(DriverDataSource.java:85)
    at org.apache.cayenne.conn.PoolManager.<init>(PoolManager.java:90)
    at org.apache.cayenne.configuration.server.XMLPoolingDataSourceFactory.getDataSource(XMLPoolingDataSourceFactory.java:64)
    at org.apache.cayenne.configuration.server.DelegatingDataSourceFactory.getDataSource(DelegatingDataSourceFactory.java:68)
    at org.apache.cayenne.configuration.server.DataDomainProvider.createAndInitDataDomain(DataDomainProvider.java:203)
    at org.apache.cayenne.configuration.server.DataDomainProvider.get(DataDomainProvider.java:111)
    ... 12 more
```

please help me

Answer (score 1):

This response is for those who are still facing this issue.

I faced the same issue. I found the following fix (Courtsey "Andrus" posted at nabble.com). This has fixed my oracle issue.

Are you getting this error when connecting from CayenneModeler GUI?

If so you need to go to "Tools -> Preferences -> ClassPath" and click
on "Add Jar/Zip" button and navigate to the Oracle driver jar file (a
file like ojdbc14.jar). Once you add the path to the driver, click
"Save" and you should be able to connect.

source: http://cayenne.195.n3.nabble.com/Problem-connecting-oracle-10-td718.html

I think he replied better at nabble.com. I can see his post before mine! ;)

Comment: Thanks.  This helped me, although I'm not certain the original post was what I was looking for.  I'm not going to dig through those errors, haha.  Anyway, I did have to download the driver for mysql, which I thought Cayenne came with for some reason.  Either way, it worked, so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure mysql driver jar is on classpath of your application

Comment: hey Andrus your response is better at nabble.com I copied it from there, thanks :)